# Exited segmentation fault Struct in C

Tags: c, struct, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have a struct and I want to make a function with a loop taking from user inputs and store them into the struct. But after 1 loop the program crashes with segmentation fault and I can't find the problem.

**Here is the error:**

[image]

```sh
> clang-7 -pthread -lm -o main main.c
> ./main
4
ath
67
68
thes
exited, segmentation fault
>
```

**Here is the code:**

```
#define STR 100000
typedef struct city{
 float x;
 float y;
 char *name;
}City;

City *GetCities(int *N){
int i;
City *p;
char c;
scanf("%d",&*N);
p=malloc(sizeof(City));
p->name=malloc(STR*sizeof(char));

if (p->name==NULL){
  printf("Could not find enough memory");
}

for (i=0; i<*N; i++){
   while((c = getchar()) !='\n' && c!= EOF);
   fgets(p[i].name,STR,stdin);
   p[strcspn(p[i].name,"\n")].name="\0";
   p[i].name=realloc(p[i].name,(strlen(p[i].name)+1)*sizeof(char));
   scanf("%f ",&p[i].x);
   scanf("%f",&p[i].y);
} 
return p;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you instantly and exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. Get that minimum info and post it in the question. Can also use the debugger to examine the state at the crash point and also leading up to it.

Comment: `p[i].name`, `p` is not an array

Comment: why do you want to do this thing: `scanf("%d",&*N);`

Comment: @IrAM scanf is how many time Cities user wants to store into the struct.How i can make p to be an array with elements of struct (string name,x,y)?

Comment: @VasilisNakos I think you miss the point of @IrAM's comment.   `&*N` is a syntax error.

Comment: Mixing `getchar`, `fgets`, and `scanf` is a really bad idea.

Comment: Failing to check the values returned by `fgets` and `scanf` is also a concern.

Comment: Checking that `malloc` failed is only useful if the program same action other than merely printing a message.  Write the error message to stderr, and return immediately.

Comment: @WilliamPursell `&*N` is not a syntax error. `&*&*N` is also valid. Check it [here](https://ideone.com/u3SXHd). Not very useful, but valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one will work:

```
//includes were missing
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR 100000
typedef struct city{
 float x;
 float y;
 char *name;
}City;

City *GetCities(int *N){
  int i;
  char c;
  City *list, *city;
  //N is already a pointer so using a '&*' is confusing and I'm unsure whether this is at all valid syntax
  scanf("%d", N);
  //allocate enough memory! multiplied by number of cities
  list = malloc(sizeof(City) * (*N));
  
  for (i=0; i < *N; i++) {
     //use pointer arithmetic to get the current city from the allocated block
     //this needs to be done only once, now you can go on and reuse it extensively
     city = list + i;
     
     city->name = malloc(STR * sizeof(char));
     if (city->name==NULL){
       printf("Could not find enough memory");
     }
     while((c = getchar()) !='\n' && c!= EOF);
     //i hope rest is clear
     fgets(city->name, STR, stdin);
//use city->name[strlen(city->name)-1]='\0' instead?
     city->name[strcspn(city->name,"\n")]='\0';
     //at least you didn't forget the +1 in the realloc! :-)
     city->name = realloc(city->name,(strlen(city->name)+1)*sizeof(char));
     scanf("%f ", &city->x);
     scanf("%f",  &city->y);
  }
  
  return list;
}

//please also show the main, but I guess it was something like this
int main () {
    int i, n;
    City *cities, *city;
    cities = GetCities(&n);
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        city = cities + i;
        printf("The %dth city \"%s\" got coordinates x=%f and y=%f!\n", i, city->name, city->x, city->y);
        //don't forget to free the name
        free(city->name);
    }
    //don't forget to free the memory
    free(cities);
}
```

I would also recommend to use a smaller line length buffer and run fgets in a loop to save ram space.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a poor design choice to require the input to include a total count of the data that is to come, and it's fairly easy to remove that requirement.   For example:

```
    #include <stddef.h>                                                                
    #include <stdio.h>                                                                 
    #include <stdlib.h>                                                                
                                                                                       
    FILE * xfopen(const char *, const char *);                                         
    void * xrealloc(void *, size_t, size_t, void *);                                   
                                                                                       
    struct city{                                                                       
            float x, y;                                                                
            char *name;                                                                
    };                                                                                 
                                                                                       
    int                                                                                
    get_city(struct city *e)                                                           
    {                                                                                  
            int c;                                                                     
            char *end;                                                                 
            size_t cap = 32;                                                           
            e->name = xrealloc(NULL, 1, cap, &end); 
            /* Copy one line.  We coould use getline(), or "%m[^\n]" */
            while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' ){                              
                    *end++ = c;                                                        
                    if( end == e->name + cap ){                                        
                            e->name = xrealloc(e->name, 1, cap += 32, &end);           
                    }                                                                  
            }                                                                          
            *end = '\0';                                                               
            if( c == EOF ){                                                            
                    return EOF;                                                        
            }                                                                          
            if( (c = scanf("%f %f ", &e->x, &e->y)) != 2 ){                            
                    if( c != EOF ){                                                    
                            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");                        
                    }                                                                  
                    return EOF;                                                        
            }                                                                          
            return 0;                                                                  
    }                                                                                  
                                                                                       
    struct city *                                                                      
    GetCities(int *n)                                                                  
    {                                                                                  
            size_t cap = 4;                                                            
            struct city *e, *p = xrealloc(NULL, sizeof *p, cap, &e);                   
            while( get_city(e) != EOF ){                                               
                    if( ++e == p + cap ){                                              
                            p = xrealloc(p, sizeof *p, cap += 4, &e);                  
                    }                                                                  
            }                                                                          
            *n = e - p;                                                                
            return p;                                                                  
    }

    int                                                                                
    main(void)                                                                         
    {                                                                                  
            int n;                                                                     
            while( (n = getchar()) != EOF && n != '\n' ){                              
                    ;  /* Discard first line of input */                               
            }                                                                          
            struct city *p = GetCities(&n);                                            
            struct city *e = p + n;                                                    
                                                                                       
            for( ; p < e; p++ ){                                                       
                    printf("%s: %f, %f\n", p->name, p->x, p->y);                       
            }                                                                          
            return 0;                                                                  
    }                                                                                  
                                                                                       
    void *                                                                             
    xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *endvp)                           
    {                                                                                  
            char **endp = endvp;                                                       
            char *b = buf;                                                             
            ptrdiff_t offset = b && endp && *endp ? *endp - b : 0;                     
            b = realloc(b, num * siz);                                                 
            if( b == NULL ){                                                           
                    perror("realloc");                                                 
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
            }                                                                          
            if( endp != NULL ){                                                        
                    *endp = b + offset;                                                
            }                                                                          
            return b;                                                                  
    }
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic involving void pointers is undefined.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Thank you!  I knew there was something smelly about that function.  Have changed to `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three essential things you need to do to make your program work:

1. Allocate N cities
2. For each city, allocate memory for the name before reading the name
3. Terminate name correctly (assign a null character, not a string)

Here is the corrected code:

```
City *GetCities(int *N)
{
    int i;
    City *p;
    char c;

    scanf("%d", N);
    p = malloc(*N * sizeof(City));
    for (i = 0; i < *N; i++) {
        p[i].name = malloc(STR * sizeof(char));
        if (p[i].name == NULL) {
            printf("Could not find enough memory");
        }
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        fgets(p[i].name, STR, stdin);
        p[i].name[strcspn(p[i].name, "\n")] = '\0';
        scanf("%f ", &p[i].x);
        scanf("%f", &p[i].y);
    }
    return p;
}
```

What's left is to validate the input and make sure that the first call to malloc doesn't fail. You probably also need a function which frees the allocated memory.